# AWS SQS with two queues and one consumer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

If I have two Amazon SQS simple queues and one consumer, how can the consumer consume the messages from both queues?

I have two producers that produce messages on two different SQS queues. How can one consumer that is listening to both queues consume the messages?

Answer (score 3):

The term "consumer" is applied to code that calls `ReceiveMessage()` on an Amazon SQS queue (since it *consumes* messages).

For a consumer to consume messages from multiple queues, it would need to call `ReceiveMessage()` on both queues (separately). There is no single command that consumes messages on multiple queues.

For a consumer to "listen to both queues", it would need to call `ReceiveMessage()` on both queues.